# Publishing non-jar files in gradle

Tags: gradle

I am having a set of files (specifically a set of json documents) that I need to publish to my Maven repository.

How do I use publishing and specify the directory in the artifact.

```
publications {
    myPublication(MavenPublication) {
        artifact(/path/to/dir>) // directory that contains files to publish
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a task to zip all your documents and then publish the zip.

```
task jsonZip(type: Zip) {
    source file(/path/to/dir)
}

publications {
    myPublication(MavenPublication) {
        artifact jsonZip.archivePath
    }

}
```